# How to secure REST GET method?

Tags: rest, http, security, https, owasp

HTTP GET method will transfer data over the url as in `https://www.example.com/users?id=1`. If I use HTTPS the connection will be secure but the sensitive data in the link could still be logged on the server uppon processing the link requested by the client, exposing secrets to be acquired by some hacker later.

[OWASP recommends](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet) not storing anything on the links, as it can be logged on the web server.

But REST uses GET to retrieve data, as a "Read" would in a `CRUD` operation.

So the question is, **How can I make a secure GET call on REST?**

---

EDIT: One example: OWASP says to NOT include an API Key on the URL address, but since all data sent on a GET request is placed on the URL, **how would I send the API Key to the server in other to authorize the GET response from that user, since I can't place it on the URL itself?**

OWASP doesn't explain how to achieve this.

Comment: You should be a bit more specific on what that sensitive data really is. Different kinds of data require different kinds of protection.

Comment: I mean any data that if logged will be compromised. It's not a matter on how to secure the internal data transmitted over a GET, but on how to use GET securely.

Comment: That I have understood. So again: What kind of data?

Comment: See the edit, I gave an example that might enlighten things a bit further.

Comment: It is still not entirely clear what you are trying to protect. Is this all about authentication/authorization?

Comment: Yes, I am just trying to understand the link I posted...se it here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet under the first topic: "Authentication and session management"

Answer (score 3):

> EDIT: One example: OWASP says to NOT include an API Key on the URL address, but since all data sent on a GET request is placed on the URL, how would I send the API Key to the server in other to authorize the GET response from that user, since I can't place it on the URL itself?

You're wrong that all data must be specified in the URL. There's a lot of stuff that actually goes into HTTP headers! Instead of an API key in a url, you should use an `Authorization` header.

Comment: I am new to REST web programming, all AJAX request I saw on vanilla javascript and jquery passed all the data on the GET URL for the sever.

Comment: @mFeinstein k well now you know what to look for.